# General rule for specific determinant $n\times n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Is there any way to write the determinant in function of $n$? Recursive formula or Vieta's formula for roots $(x)$ or any possible transformation to trigonometric form that determinant can be written in function of $n$?

$
D_n = \left| 
 \begin{matrix}
 x & f(-1)  & f(-2)  & f(-3)  & f(-4)  & \cdots   & f (2-n) & f (1-n) \\
 f(1) & x & f(-1)  &f (-2)  & f(-3)  & \cdots  &  f (3-n) & f (2-n) \\
 f(2) & f(1) & x & f(-1)  &f (-2)  & \cdots  &  f (4-n) & f (3-n) \\
 f(3) & f(2) & f(1) & x & f(-1)  & \cdots  &  f (5-n) & f (4-n) \\
 f(4) & f(3) & f(2) & f(1) & x & \cdots  & f (6-n) &  f (5-n) \\
 \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots   & \vdots    \\
 f (n-2) & f (n-3) & f (n-4) & f (n-5) & f (n-6) & \cdots  & x & f(-1)  \\
 f (n-1) & f (n-2) & f (n-3) & f (n-4) & f (n-5) & \cdots  &  f(1)  & x \\
 \end{matrix}
\right|
$

Or given in simpler notation for example for $4$th order $(4\times4)$.

$
D_4 = \left| 
 \begin{matrix}
 x & b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
 a_1 & x & b_1 & b_2 \\
 a_2 & a_1 & x & b_1 \\
 a_3 & a_2 & a_1 & x \\
 \end{matrix}
\right|
$

How to find general determinant rule for $n$?

Comment: Why do you think that a closed formula exist (even if you restrict yourself to a polynomial $f$) ? IMHO, it's a much too general question, not worth to spend time on it.

Comment: Take a look for 4th order, maybe some idea or suggestion? Why do you think that it is interesting to present only problems which already have solutions?

Comment: First of all, could you say us in which context you have been interested by this determinant ? It could help to understand, and maybe transdorm the issue ? Besides, there are indeed an infinite variety of problems that have not already been solved, some of them bringing fresh air, but among them, a little experience make me think that (look, I have said IMHO) this one will not have a valuable answer.  Once again, maybe I am wrong.

Comment: if you have any idea, write, if you do not have again ok. Lot of solved problems found the point many centuries later. Thank you for your interest anyway.

Comment: Please say us a little in which context you are interested by this determinant.

Comment: solutions are giving only one part of the frequency equation in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As the matrix you give belongs to the category of "Toeplitz matrices", you can be interested by the following paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.4990.pdf).

Comment: Thank you Marie, I appreciate. Maybe it will help me.